# Got this error when initializing a variable Incompatible types. Found: 'android.widget.ListView', required: 'java.util.List<class_name>'

Tags: java, android, xml

Far as I understand what the error say is it expects me to provide a `List` instead of a `ListView`

but casting to java.util.List does not solve the problem, instead it just creates more errors.

what should I do in this case?

My end goal is to make a ListView that shows the result of users query with each iteration
any help to point out what is actually goin on and what do I have to do is very appreciated

Here is the relevant code :

Varible :

```
private List<Absensi> list_absensi = new ArrayList<Absensi>();
```

Initialization :

```
list_absensi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListAbsensi);
//the problem is in this line of code
```

XML ID for ListView :

```
<ListView
      android:id="@+id/ListAbsensi"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**I also have adapter for this :**

```
public class AbsensiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Absensi> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Absensi> absensis;
    Picasso mypicasso;

    public AbsensiAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<Absensi> objects, Picasso myotherpicasso) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.absensis = objects;
        this.mypicasso = myotherpicasso;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int  pos, View convertview, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_absensi, parent, false);

        TextView txtabsenID = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtAViewId);
        TextView txtasbsenTanggal = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtAViewTanggal);
        TextView txtasbsenKelas = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtAViewKelas);
        TextView txtasbsenGuru = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtAViewGuru);

        txtabsenID.setText(String.format("id : %s", absensis.get(pos).getID()));
        txtasbsenTanggal.setText(String.format("Tanggal : %s",absensis.get(pos).getID()));
        txtasbsenKelas.setText(String.format("Kelas : %s",absensis.get(pos).getID()));
        txtasbsenGuru.setText(String.format("Guru : %s",absensis.get(pos).getID()));

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //start activity AbsensiDetailActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AbsensiDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("absensi_id", String.valueOf(absensis.get(pos).getID()));
                intent.putExtra("absensi_tanggal", absensis.get(pos).getTanggal());
                intent.putExtra("absensi_kelas", absensis.get(pos).getKelasName());
                intent.putExtra("absensi_guru", absensis.get(pos).getGuruName());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

list_absensi.xml for showing the result

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAViewId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            tools:text="ID"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAViewTanggal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            tools:text="Tanggal" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAViewKelas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            tools:text="Kelas" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAViewGuru"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            tools:text="Guru" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAViewPelajaran"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            tools:text="Pelajaran" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your root of the problems:

```
list_absensi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListAbsensi);
```

Function `findViewById` returns object type of View. `list_absensi` is a view which at this case it is a `ListView` (you declared it in xml).

So the top declaration for your ListView should be:

```
private ListView list_absensi;
```

I have a strong feeling that you mess view with a container for storing data. `ListView` is for displaying the items. If you want to store data - you must use a list. At this case your should at top of your declarations add a new variable for storing data should be:

```
private List<Absensi> absensis = new ArrayList<Absensi>();
```

Comment: I tried your answer but changing variable name does not work

Comment: It's not about changing the variable's name but to use two different variables to two different purposes.

Comment: yes, it's actually works, but I still don't understand why?

Comment: ok, but my previous ListAbsensi and list_absensi are 2 different variables with different purposes too? ListAbsensi is a ListView variable for View, and list_absensi is a List for storing data. But what you did here (and works) is essentially changing the name of my ListView and List variables name. So why doesn't it works with the previous variables name?

Comment: ah yes I understand where I am wrong now. Thank you very much. I should have used more distinct variabl name in the future

Comment: Correct. Try to use better names for variables and everything will be more clear.